# Playing FLV files

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to play FLV files directly from internet or from local file in C# i have tried to use Shockwave Flash Object but i am facing a lot of problems with it so

Question : Is there a library for playing FLV files in c# with functions like PLAY, PAUSE, STOP, SEEK... ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [.NET VLC library](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) that should allow you to play these videos.